# Integral of a special combination of polynomial and exponential functions

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, exponential-function

I am trying to solve the following integral where $x$ is a random variable from a sub-Gaussian distribution while $c\geq 2$ and $\beta>0$:

$$\int_0^\infty x^{c-1} \exp{\left(-\frac{x^c}{\beta^c}-\frac{x^2}{2 \beta^2}\right)} dx $$

I know the solution to the following known integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^n \exp\,(-a x^b)\,dx = \frac{1}{b}\, a^{-\frac{n+1}{b}} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{b} \right) $$

However, the exponential function in my problem has a polynomial power. Can anyone please help me through this?

Comment: Should that be $\exp[-|x/\beta|^c - x^2/(2\beta^2)]$?

Comment: Sure, thanks I edited.

Comment: (1) You don't need absolute values in your integral, since everything is positive. (2) Your integral doesn't converge—both the polynomial factor and the exponential factor are tending to infinity with $x$. (3) Your evaluation of the "known integral" is incorrect—it is missing a factor of $\Gamma(\frac{n+1}b)$.

Comment: Thanks, Grey! I edited my post accordingly. Would my integral converge if in the formulation I have $\exp(\frac{-x^c}{\beta^c}-\frac{x^2}{2 \beta^2})$ instead of $\exp(\frac{x^c}{\beta^c}-\frac{x^2}{2 \beta^2})$?